# Passwords won't get hashed and password input not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently trying to improve my knowledge in coding only by using class-based views. I am currently using Django 2.0.7 and I got a bit stuck. I was trying to extend the User model in order to create accounts. This was easily done. But I can't make the passwords to get hashed. Also, when I try to type, it will not be hidden even when using PasswordInput widget. Any advice ?

```html
#models.py
class Client(User):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                             validators=[
                                 RegexValidator(
                                     regex='^[0-9+]+',
                                     message='Not a valid phone number.',
                                 ),
                             ])
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Client'

#forms.py
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'name', 'surname', 'phone', 'address')
        model = Client


#views.py
class HomeView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = Client
    form = ClientForm
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'name', 'surname', 'phone', 'address')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Answer (score 1):

After you created your own user model **without password**, use the `set_password()` method to assign a password to your user object.

```
Ex: your_object.set_password(<psswd>)
```